# Odds that a string of N digits contains two or more of the same

Tags: code-golf, math, arithmetic, probability-theory

I have to fill in 2fa codes all day. They're 6-digit strings. One day I noticed that not once did any of these codes contain 6 unique digits, like 198532 There was always at least one double, like 198539 (here it's 9).

For any given uniformly random string of \$N\$ digits in the set \$\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}\$, what is the odds for this happening?

Your input is a single positive integer, \$N\$, with \$N \le 10\$

Your output is a number between 0 and 1, which is the probability that a string with \$N\$ digits has at least one repetition.

The shortest code wins

Comment: Could you include test cases? Do N-digit numbers include ones with leading zeros?

Comment: _For any given random number_ Do you mean uniformly random? Please specify the distribution

Comment: What is the margin of possible values of the input _N_? Can it exceed 10? Also, should the output be the probability of no repetitions, or the probability of at least one repetition?

Comment: I'm not the asker, but non-uniformly distributed 2FA codes would be extremely strange... (and the question title suggests that the output should be the probability of at least one repetition)

Comment: this is essentially the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: I have made some edits that hopefully answer all of your questions

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 30 bytes

```hs
f n=1-product[1,0.9..1.1-n/10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsIwFEbhV/kpCC2YmDt0sFAnV8HBre0QNcFichNiCr59DC5nO99Lf97GubL6GFLGzXyzvKaVsy0WPJKIKTy3R55or@RRSpIk@EBqKV6vjBFexwvamSFOiP8Rza6XyqK2tzM3YLTVwjDgHLa7M12HSVWKlvID)

If we pick, for example, 4 digits sequentially, then the odds of each one being "fresh" is

- \$10/10\$ for the first digit
- \$9/10\$ for the second digit (it must ≠ the first digit)
- \$8/10\$ for the third digit (it must ≠ the first and second digits)
- \$7/10\$ for the fourth digit (it must ≠ the first, second and third digits)

so the probability of getting 4 unique digits is \$\frac{10}{10}\cdot\frac{9}{10}\cdot\frac{8}{10}\cdot\frac{7}{10}\$, and the probability of *not* getting 4 unique digits (i.e. some repetition) is one minus that.

In general the answer is $$1 - \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{10-k}{10}.$$

(Though not required, this formula is also valid for \$N \geq 11\$, where the answer is \$1\$. In that case, this product contains a factor 0, representing the fact that we can't possibly pick an eleventh digit that is different from all ten digits that exist.)

Comment: [29 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsIwFEbhV/kpCG0hMXfoUqiTq@Dg1naImmCwuQkxBd8@Bpezne@lP2@zbcX5GFLGzXyzvCbH2RYLnkjEFJ77I89EgqUktR5J9T0Xrx1jgtfxgnZhiBPi/0NzGKSyqB3swg0YbaUwjjiH/b6ZrsOsKkVr@QE "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

Uses the same formula as Lynn's Haskell answer.

-1 byte thanks to [Dominic van Essen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/95126/dominic-van-essen)!

```
Ḷ÷⁵CPC
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm2Htz9q3Ooc4Pzf0BDEa3/UtCbyPwA)

```
Ḷ         lowered range:                    [0, 1, ..., n-1]
 ÷⁵       divide each value by 10           [0/10, 1/10, ..., (n-1)/10]
   C      complement, subtract each from 1  [10/10, 9/10, ..., (11-n)/10]
    P     take the product of all values    (10/10)*(9/10)* ... *(11-n)/10
     C    complement                        1 - (10/10)*(9/10)* ... *(11-n)/10
```

Comment: Good explanation, so I guess that ```Ḷ÷⁵CPC``` should work, too (my first ever attempt at Jelly...)

Comment: @DominicvanEssen thanks a lot, I missed that. I didn't get past guessing the order of builtins yet either ;)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 9 bytes

```
₀~εrΠ?↵/⌐
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%80%7E%CE%B5r%CE%A0%3F%E2%86%B5%2F%E2%8C%90&inputs=9&header=&footer=)

Me and the boys on our way to port Lynn's Haskell answer be like.

### Explained

```
₀~εrΠ?↵/⌐
₀~εr       # the range (10 - input, 10]
    Π      # the product of that
       /   # divided by
     ?↵    # 10 ** input
        ⌐  # 1 - that
```

Comment: [8 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%CA%81%E2%82%80-%CE%A0%3F%E2%86%B5%2F%E2%8C%90&inputs=9&header=&footer=)

Comment: [Alternate 8 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%E2%82%8C%E2%80%B9%C2%BD*.9e%E2%8C%90&inputs=9&header=&footer=) (port of @EliteDaMyth's answer)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÇnA /AÃ×n1
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=x25BIC9Bw9duMQ&input=OA)

```
ÇnA /AÃ×n1     :Implicit input of integer U
Ç              :Map the range [0,U]
 n             :  Subtract from
  A            :  10
    /A         :  Divide by 10
      Ã        :End map
       ×       :Reduce by multiplication
        n1     :Subtract from 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
1-10!/10^#/(10-#)!&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b731DX0EBR39AgTllfw9BAV1lTUe1/QFFmXkm0sq5dmoOyjpKCrYKSjp8DkB2rVhecnJhXF5SYl54abaBjaBD7HwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 13 bytes

```
1-!*(!%^~)&10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/DXUVtTQUVePqNNUMDf5rcqUmZ@QrpCkYwhhGMIYxjGECY1jCFRv8BwA)

- 1 minus `1-` the factorial of the input `!` times `*`...
- `(!%^~)&10` the input choose 10 divided by 10 raised to the  input.

Or, equivalenly:

```
1-!*!&10%10&^
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>39</s> 38 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x and(x-1-f(x-1)*(x-11))/10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcQxDoAgDADA3Vd0pEai1Y3Ex2Cw2kQLIQz4etQbLj3ljLq0xuvl7y14qK6C12CqJcv/2P8T4khT45hBQBSy12M3NKPr4JOyaDEysBHE9gI)

- Thanks to @ovs for -1

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##FcQxDoAgDADA3Vd0pEai1Y3Ex2Cw2kQLIQz4etQbLj3ljLq0xuvl7y14qK6C12CqJcv/2P8T4khT45hBQBSy12M3NKPr4JOyaDEysBHE9gI) by looking at alternate forms of the expression of WolframAlpha

Comment: @ovs I knew there was an optimization but I couldn't find it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

```
Tses°/1α
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W9o6OZnr6Sga6egZO/n9z@kOLX40AZ9w3Mb/@v8BwA)

Uses a different formula from the Wikipedia page:

$$ 1-{_{365}P_{n} \over 10^n} $$

```python
Ts        # push 10 and swap implicit input n to the front
  e       # number of permutations
   s°     # 10 ** n
     /    # divide: nPr(10, n) / 10 ** n
      1α  # absolute difference from 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), <sup><s>13</s></sup> 12 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Implements the same formula as Lynn's Haskell answer.

```
1-(×/1-.1×⍳)
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=M9TVODxd31BXz/Dw9Ee9mzUB&f=e9Q31dP/UdsEA65HvZ2P2iZWKGikHVqhUAEUetS72dBQEwA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

And 15 bytes with \$1-{1\over 10^n} {10!\over (10-n)!}\$:

```
10∘(1-*÷⍨⊣÷⍥!-)
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=MzR41DFDw1BX6/D2R70rHnUtBtFLFXU1AQ&f=e9Tb@ahtYoWCRtqhFQoVj9omHFpvqP2od7OhoSYA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=train&n=f)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 11 bytes

```
Ｉ⁻¹ΠＥＮ∕⁻χιχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzczr7RYw1BHIaAoP6U0GSiQWKDhmVdQWuJXmpuUWqShqaPgklmWmZIKU2qgo5AJFDQ00AQD6///zf7rluUAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
     Ｎ      Input integer
    Ｅ       Map over implicit range
        χ   Predefined variable `10`
       ⁻    Subtract
         ι  Current index
      ∕     Divided by
          χ Predefined variable `10`
   Π        Take the product
 ⁻¹         Subtract from 1
Ｉ           Cast to string
            Implicitly print
```

Alternative approach, also 11 bytes:

```
Ｉ⁻¹Π∕⁻χ…⁰Ｎχ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzczr7RYw1BHIaAoP6U0uUTDJbMsMyUVJm6goxCUmJeeqgFkeOYVlJb4leYmpRZpaGrqKBgaaIKA9f//Zv91y3IA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
       …⁰Ｎ  Range from 0 to input integer
     ⁻χ     Vectorised subtract from 10
    ∕     χ Vectorised divide by 10
Ｉ⁻¹Π        Cast product subtracted from 1 to string
```